# Why did Cap say, "About what we were saying"?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

Banner says to group of kids, who just clicked photos with him:

> Banner: Listen to your mom. She knows better.
>
> Captain America: **About what we were saying**.
>
> Banner: Right. The whole time travel do-over? Eh, guys, it's outside
>   of my area of expertise.

Why did Cap say, "About what we were saying"?

Comment: You might be better off learning a bit more English. I don't mean to be rude but the quote you've included shows why he says it.

Comment: Script *vs.* Screenplay: https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/10309/what-are-the-differences-between-a-script-and-a-screenplay

Comment: @Shreedhar Why are you linking that post? I can't see what you're trying to clear up here.

Comment: She's looking for the inner meaning of the script. I thought its better for her to understand this, idk.. A screenplay would maybe help her understand some things behind the dialogues. just a thought though.

Comment: @Shreedhar Ah fair enough makes sense. Of course I don't think there has been either the script or screenplay released for Endgame (or any of the more recent MCU films at all for that matter).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cap is trying to get the conversation back on track and away from Bruce talking to the kids that have approached him. This is made clear with Banner's very next sentence that you included in the question.

> **Smart Hulk:** Right. The whole time travel do-over? Eh, guys, it's outside of my area of expertise.
>
> <sub>*Avengers: Endgame*</sub>

He says *"Right. The whole time travel do-over?"* which is *"what they were saying"* (talking about).